# Using SQL to create an ID X-ref table

Tags: sql, netezza

Using SQL, I am trying to group ids together that are associated together.  For each associated group of ids, I need to keep the minimum value as the group id and then list all distinct values within the group as the unique id.  The input data comes in the sequence shown below and associated ids are always on adjacent rows.

```
--SAMPLE INPUT DATA  
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE INPUT_TBL  
  (ID1  INTEGER,  
   ID2  INTEGER);  

INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 101,105;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 105,102;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 102,105;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 204,210;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 210,203;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 203,210;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 301,302;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 302,303;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 303,307;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 307,305;  
INSERT INTO INPUT_TBL (ID1,ID2) SELECT 305,307;
```

**Input File**

```
Id-1 Id-2  
101  105  
105  102  
102  105  
204  210  
210  203  
203  210  
301  302  
302  303  
303  307  
307  305  
305  307
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Group Id    Unq Id  
101         101  
101         105  
101         102  
203         204  
203         210  
203         203  
301         301  
301         302  
301         303  
301         307  
301         305
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.  This appears to require recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
with ids as
(
Select Id1 as ID from INPUT_TBL
union 
Select Id2 as ID from INPUT_TBL
),
iGroups as 
(
select cast(id/100 as int) as iGroup, min(ID) as groupID
from ids
group by cast(id/100 as int)
)
select ig.GroupID, ids.id as UnqID
from ids 
inner join iGroups ig on cast(ids.id/100 as int) = ig.iGroup
order by ig.GroupID, ids.id;
```

Comment: The logic provided works for the sample data, but dividing by 100 will not work on the real data to group them together.

Comment: @SteveS how would we know to make the grouping by? You did not provide a logic and the logic deducted from sample output matches this. Whatever your logic is, apply it to grouping.

Comment: The data comes in sequenced with related ids together.  One way to tell when a you are in the last record in the group is when id2 is equal to id1 from the prior record.